# Which data structure is appropriate for this?

Tags: python, algorithm, list, data-structures

I have a line in my code that currently does this at each step `x`:

```
myList = [(lo,hi) for lo,hi in myList if lo <= x <= hi]
```

This is pretty slow. Is there a more efficient way to eliminate things from a list that don't contain a given `x`?

Comment: It can be. Part of my problem is that I wasn't sure *how* to sort it (as each element in the list is a pair (lo,hi) where lo <= hi), as it depends on the intended data structure.

Comment: What's the type and range of `x`,`lo`,`hi`. A fast solution could be completely different when talking about unbounded floats, or relatively low integers, for example.

Comment: Tuples are sorted lexicographically, so by `lo` first, `hi` second. If sorted, you can use bisection to find a suitable `lo` and limit the number of matches greatly.

Comment: If you sort by `lo`, you can use binary search to eliminate cases where `lo > x`. For something more complicated, you can try R-trees

Comment: How many x's do you have? How big is the list of intervals?

Comment: Are you sure you need a list? You could use generator expressions and skip allocations https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/

Comment: Do you expect high or low selectivity? (Will x intersect with >10% or very few intervals)?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you're looking for an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). From Wikipedia:

> In computer science, an interval tree is an ordered tree data structure to hold intervals. Specifically, it allows one to efficiently find all intervals that overlap with any given interval or point.

So, instead of storing the `(lo, hi)` pairs sequentially in a list, you would have them define the intervals in an interval tree. Then you could perform queries on the tree with `x`, and retain only the intervals that overlap `x`.

Comment: Also see http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-11-augmenting-data-structures-dynamic-order-statistics-interval-trees/ :-) The problem rang a *vague* bell..

Comment: I did try interval trees earlier but could not get a fast implementation working. There wasn't a whole lot of good examples online either that does what I am looking for specifically (removing from a dynamic list)

Comment: @ArukaJ I found a few implementations that appear to do what you want; one is [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/intervaltree/2.0.4). You could also check out the library in Ami Tavory's answer.

Comment: @arshajii That code is super long and complicated. Is there anything that is barebones?

Comment: Downvoter, please leave a comment so that I can fix/improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

While you don't give much context, I'll assume the rest of the loop looks like:

`for x in xlist:
      myList = [(lo,hi) for lo,hi in myList if lo <= x <= hi]`

In this case, if may be more efficient to construct an interval tree (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) first. Then, for each `x` you walk the tree and find all intervals which intersect with `x`; add these intervals to a set as you find them.

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm going to suggest what may seem like a really dumb solution favoring micro-optimizations over algorithmic ones. It'll depend on your specific needs.

The ultimate question is this: is a *single* linear pass over your array (list in Python), on average, expensive? In other words, is searching for lo/high pairs that contain `x` going to generally yield results that are very small (ex: 1% of the overall size of the list), or relatively quite large (ex: 25% or more of the original list)?

If the answer is the latter, you might actually get a more efficient solution keeping a basic, contiguous, cache-friendly representation that you're accessing sequentially. The hardware cache excels at plowing through contiguous data where multiple adjacent elements fit into a cache line sequentially.

What you want to avoid in such a case is the expensive linear-time removal from the middle of the array as well as possibly the construction of a new one. If you trigger a linear-time operation for every single individual element you remove from the array, then naturally that's going to get very expensive very quickly.

To exchange that linear-time operation for a much faster constant-time one, all we have to do when we want to remove an element at a certain index in the array is to overwrite the element at that index with the element at the back of the array (last element). Now simply remove the redundant duplicate from the back of the array (a removal from the back of an array is a constant-time operation, and often involves just basic arithmetical instructions).

If your needs fit the criteria, then this can actually give you better results than a smarter algorithm. It's one of the peculiar cases where the practice can trump the theory due to the skewed performance of the hardware cache over DRAM, but if you're performing these types of hi/lo queries repeatedly and wanting to get very narrow results, then something smarter like an interval tree or at least sorting the data to allow binary searches can be considerably better.